# How to avoid DPI awareness in a QtApplication for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtwebkit

I have a QtWebKit application and I want to avoid DPI awareness. I tried adding a manifest as documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it only worked in Windows 8.1 (not in Windows 8 and lower versions.)

Inspecting the Qt source code (4.7) I found inside the file `qapplication_win.cpp` the following snippet:

```
// Notify Vista and Windows 7 that we support highter DPI settings
ptrSetProcessDPIAware = (PtrSetProcessDPIAware)
    QLibrary::resolve(QLatin1String("user32"), "SetProcessDPIAware");
if (ptrSetProcessDPIAware)
    ptrSetProcessDPIAware();
```

For more information take a look at the [Commit](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/yb-qt/commit/db24e82b6b74be303492f186a45d784fcd84fdc6)

That said, I don't really know why it's working in Windows 8.1 and more importantly how can I disable this Qt feature... any Macro/Qt API I should use?

Comment: I don't have knowledge on the subject, but if that commit introduces the problem for you, why not [revert that commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html), and compile Qt.

Comment: @sashoalm thanks! Indeed I did that and it worked properly. I just want it to know why at first glance we don't have the chance to disable this feature considering that Windows in its documentation explicitly say you can do it thru a manifest. I think Qt should provide a way to avoid this DPI awareness but may be I'm loosing an important reason why it's like this.